# One model finds custom validator, others not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, customvalidator

I built the custom validator ExactLengthValidator, which I saved in lib/custom_validations.rb.
In included it in environment.rb with `require 'custom_validations'`

It works well in one model by writing:

```
validates :bic, :presence => true, :exact_length => { :exact_values => [8,11] }
```

But in another model I get the following error while starting rails console:

Unknown validator: 'exact_length' (ArgumentError)

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

if you put 'lib' into your config.autoload_paths there should be no need for the require statement, this might also fix the other issue. have a look at this link: http://thelucid.com/2010/01/08/sexy-validation-in-edge-rails-rails-3/